# where to defind DEBUG symbol for Debug build in VS2012?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I've Win32 DLL application. Debug build is selected. I wrote such code:

```
#if DEBUG
fflush(logFile);
#endif
```

But `fflush(logFile);` is grayed out so I assume it will not be executed.
But i want it to be executed. Does it mean that in Debug `DEBUG` symbol is not defined? Where can I define it in VS2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor definitions are defined under project settings as shown on screenshot (note `_DEBUG` there):

[image]

Note that in case of `_DEBUG` you want to check if it is defined at all, and not compare it (possibly missing definition) to zero. You want:

`#if defined(_DEBUG)`

or

`#ifdef _DEBUG`

Comment: Using `#if _DEBUG` is fine - it gets defaulted to `1`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a Visual Studio C++ project will have the macro `_DEBUG` defined for a Debug project configuration.  It will have the value `1`, so you can test for it using `#if` or `#ifdef`.

But note that the macro starts with an underscore - if you want to use the name `DEBUG` (maybe you have existing code that uses that name), you'll need to add it to the project properties yourself (`C/C++ | Preprocessor | Preprocessor definitions`).  Or you can put the following in a header that's included in every translation unit (maybe `stdafx.h`):

```
#if _DEBUG
#undef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 1
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Every project has two builds: Debug and Release. Debug build have `DEBUG` defined, as if you defined using:

```
#define DEBUG
```

It enables, the code to get generated differently. The writers of code (functions, classes etc), may add additional diagonistics to aid in debugging. The Debug build is for debugging only, and you don't give this build (i.e. EXE generated with Debug build), to the customers.

Another build where `DEBUG` symbols is not defined, is for Release build. A release build is for optmized code, at code level, compiler setting level, and linker level. Most of diagonistic, asserts, debugging-aid feature will be disabled - so as to produce optimized executable.

Whomsoever who has written the above code, has written the same thing in mind. To let flush the file, only if debug build is running. You can comment the `#if` and `#endif`, and let `fflush` line compiled, or you can use Release build. It all depends on you.